# Prevent double execution of a function

Tags: php, automation

I develop an online game. It has a file named `automations.php` which is responsible for all kind of automated tasks like training soldiers, processing battles  and etc. my problem is sometimes functions get executed twice:

```
class automation{
        function automation(){
            if(!file_exists('traning.txt')){
                file_put_contents('traning.txt' ,'');
                $this->train_soldiers();
            }
        }
        private function train_soldiers(){@unlink('traning.txt');}

    }
```

As you can see, `train_soldiers` should be executed only once but when there are a lot of online players , function gets executed twice (on two different requests). My question is how to solve this problem?

Comment: since you are using a file as the locking factor I would use `flock` http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php, instead of creating and deleting the file.

Comment: @cmorrissey Is there any other way than using a file? and how to use that function?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to keep the file there for future requests:

```
class automation{
    function automation(){
        if(!file_exists('traning.txt')){
            $fp = fopen('traning.txt', 'r+');
            if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX, false)) {
                $this->train_soldiers();
                flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    private function train_soldiers(){/** do all training, don't remove the file**/}
}
```

This way the next request, won't execute it.

Update 1: Added flock functionality. If that doesn't work, please advise on what you mean by it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is fully true though. The problem is that requests are async. If two requests are made at exactly the same time, the method will be executed twice or more again. This is because it's impossible to create the file instantly, there's always some delay. The problem occurs if some other request is checking for the file at that exact moment.

Comment: @TimVisée That is true. I have added flock functionality for exclusivity.

Comment: @AzizSaleh move `fclose($fp);` outside of your if statement

Comment: @AzizSaleh Looks great, nice upgrade.

Comment: @AzizSaleh I though of using flock, but that function makes my application to **wait**  which is not something that I want!

Comment: @undone flock should not let you wait. Either it gets the lock or not. If the app gets the lock, it will go ahead with the training else it won't do so.

Comment: I tried On Windows,CentOS and fedora. all the same: it waits!

Comment: @undone Try passing false as the third param for flock($fp, LOCK_EX, false). See if that still blocks it.